# how to generate bit sequence randomized over 2 bits

Tags: matlab

I have a network with 4 different types of nodes **A, B, C and D** represented by **00, 01, 10 and 11**
respectively. I want to create a random sequence of nodes, e.g. **A B D C A D C B C D (00 01 11 10 00 11   10 01 10 11)**, such that: **no_of_type A nodes > no_of_type B nodes > no_of_type C nodes**. How can i generate 
such a bit sequence using MATLAB.

Comment: Can it be `>=` or is it strictly `>`?

Comment: Your specification is insufficient. Should the values be statistically independent? Which distribution (maybe uniform)? Saying it should be "random" is not enough

Comment: I deleted the translation A -> 00, B -> 01, .. part because it seemed unnecessary for the question.

Comment: @Trilarion, how can you know if it's the bit representation or the letter representation that's unnecessary? I did a rollback, as I believe you might have changed the question entirely. Tariq, please consider editing your question. Both according to Luis' comment and if necessary, Trilarion's edit.

Comment: @RobertP I agree with the rollback because I'm not 100% sure myself but as I understand the question the formulation with A,B,C,D is completely equivalent to 00, 01, 10, 11 and therefore at least one of the two seems to be unnecessary for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `randperm` to obtain the random permuation of an ordered sequence of As, Bs, Cs and Ds where the number of As, Bs, Cs, Ds is descending. You can achieve this by drawing random numbers which have a constant sum (effectively drawing one less) and sorting them. In a simple approach you need to retry this several times because the numbers of As, Bs, Cs or Ds cannot be equal according to your specification.

Code example:

```
% total length of sequence
N = 10;

% try again until we found a list of lengths that has no equal entries
ni = [0,0];
% as long as there are two equal numbers inside
while any(diff(ni) == 0)
    % one length can be any value
    n1 = round(rand()*N);
    % only remaining
    n2 = round(rand()*(N-n1));
    % only remaining
    n3 = round(rand()*(N-n1-n2));
    % remaining
    n4 = N - n1 - n2 - n3;
    % sort
    ni = sort([n1, n2, n3, n4]);
end

% translate to A, B, C, D
r = [repmat('A', 1, ni(4)), repmat('B', 1, ni(3)), repmat('C', 1, ni(2)), repmat('D', 1, ni(1))];
r
% random permuatation
s = r(randperm(length(r)));
s
```

gives:

```
AAAAAAABBC
AABAABACAA
```

where the first one is the ordered random sequence (showing that indeed the number of As is larger than the number of Bs, ...) and the second is the desired random sequence. Translating to bits is trivial.